# Why can't python read my environment variables?

Tags: python, linux, django, environment-variables

I'm working with Django and I'm trying out to set several environment variables that define which settings are imported.

I use the following folder herarchy:

```
project_folder>
    app_folder>
    project_specific_files>
        settings>
            base.py
            local.py
```

I use [Kenneth Reitz's autoenv](https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv) to load my environment variables. I know it's working correctly because I can type `$ echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and I see this output:

```
project_specific_files.settings.local
```

But when I run `$django-admin.py runserver` I get:

```
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

Also, if I go into python shell and try to print out the env variables, I get the following:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 22 2012, 21:14:12) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> print os.environ['HOME']
/home/marco
>>> print os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/marco/.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'
```

Anyone have any clue what could be wrong? Thanks!

Also, I can type `$ django-admin.py runserver --settings='project_specific_files.settings.local` and everything will work alright 0.o

Comment: you have the `__init__.py` files inside every folder ?

Comment: @PepperoniPizza Yup, I was only missing an __init__.py at the project root folder, not sure if that's even needed. I added it just to check it out and it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is your environment variable exported?

Maybe the environment variable is defined in the current shell, but not marked as to be exported to sub processes (the python interpreter, or Django).

With bash, run: `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`

Comment: Yea.. this was the problem.. I wonder why autoenv is not exporting the variables. I think it's only sourcing them. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: IIUC autoenv only sources the `.env`. Therefore, if you want the variables in the `.env` file to be exported, then `export` them! Simply write `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=the_value` instead of just `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=the_value`.